# Using inner join to get column data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble running a query.  I am trying to join 3 tables to displays the top 10 medications by the amount of times that were prescribed in a single year.

When I run it as is I get an error message about something is wrong in either the aggregate or the Select.

This is my query:

```
 Select Count(MED_ID), MEDICATIONS.MEDICATION_NAME, ENCOUNTER.OBSDATE 
 From MEDICATIONS
 Inner JOIN ENC_MEDICATIONS On ENC_MEDICATIONS.MED_ID = MEDICATIONS.MED_ID
 Inner JOIN ENCOUNTER On ENC_MEDICATIONS.ENC_ID = ENCOUNTER.ENC_ID
 WHERE OBSDATE Between '01/01/2011' And '12/31/2011'
 GROUP BY (MEDICATION_NAME)
 ORDER BY COUNT(MED_ID) DESC
```

Then this is my table model:
[image]

Where am I going wrong in the Joins to get the result I am trying to display.

Thanks!
- Ann

Comment: You're missing the 3rd select/2nd non aggregated field in your group by statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
select Count(MED_ID), m.MEDICATION_NAME
from MEDICATIONS m Inner join
     ENC_MEDICATIONS em
     on em.MED_ID = m.MED_ID Inner JOIN
     ENCOUNTER e
     on em.ENC_ID = e.ENC_ID
where e.OBSDATE Between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31'
group by m.MEDICATION_NAME
order by COUNT(MED_ID) DESC 
limit 10;
```

Notes:

- `OBSDATE` has no purpose in the `SELECT`, given what you want to do.
- Date formats should use ISO/ANSI standards.  YYYY-MM-DD is the most readable such format.
- Use table aliases!
- Qualify *all* column names!

Comment: This worked thank you! I am a beginner, just learning how to write queries so thank you for all the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly without testing it, you need to add the group by of the second non-aggregate:

```
 Select MEDICATIONS.MEDICATION_NAME, ENCOUNTER.OBSDATE, Count(enc_medications.MED_ID)
     From MEDICATIONS
     Inner JOIN ENC_MEDICATIONS On ENC_MEDICATIONS.MED_ID = MEDICATIONS.MED_ID
     Inner JOIN ENCOUNTER On ENC_MEDICATIONS.ENC_ID = ENCOUNTER.ENC_ID
     WHERE OBSDATE Between '01/01/2011' And '12/31/2011'
     GROUP BY medications.MEDICATION_NAME, encounter.obsdate
     ORDER BY COUNT(enc_medications.MED_ID) DESC;
```

Comment: Did the query end up running?

Comment: Tried it out, no go, gives same type of error message.

Comment: There was a comma in the answer I just took out which would throw an error - otherwise the syntax should be ok now.

Comment: I saw that, I took it out and tried it again but still throwing error.

Comment: Oh I think its an alias for med_id - you're counting it without an alias but it shows up in two tables you selected.

Comment: okay so I have to be specific in the order by area too. let me try that.